# Equivalent of mysql_list_tables in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

When using PHP PDO to access the database, is there a way to list all the tables in a database?

Something like mysql_list_tables() is whats needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What about using a SQL query that does something like this :

```
show tables
```

Or, if needed, specifying the database :

```
show tables from crawler
```

And, if you only want to get some tables :

```
show tables from crawler like 'site%'
```

Actually, even if the [`mysql_list_tables()`](http://php.net/mysql_list_tables) function exists, its manual page states :

> This function is deprecated. It is
>   preferable to use `mysql_query()` to
>   issue a `SQL SHOW TABLES [FROM
>   db_name] [LIKE 'pattern']` statement
>   instead.

So, this should be quite OK with PDO, I'm guessing.

And, testing with PDO :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=crawler;host=127.0.0.1', 'crawler', 'crawler');
$result = $db->query("show tables");
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    var_dump($row[0]);
}
```

I'm getting this kind of output :

```
string 'headers' (length=7)
string 'headers_sites' (length=13)
string 'headers_sites_0' (length=15)
...
string 'headers_sites_7' (length=15)
string 'reporting_sites_servers_software' (length=32)
string 'servers' (length=7)
string 'sites' (length=5)
string 'sites_0' (length=7)
...
string 'sites_servers' (length=13)
string 'sites_software' (length=14)
string 'software' (length=8)
```

Which fits with the tables I actually have in this database.

Comment: Yes. This will work as long as the "show tables" query syntax is valid for all the PDO supported database drivers. 

Is this the case?

Comment: For example, Postgres uses "\dt" to list tables and not "Show Tables". So if our goal is cross-database compatibility (using PDO), then this way will not work.

Comment: @saintsjd : probably not, unfortunatly :-(  ;; going through the sources of the Doctrine ORM framework, the query used to list the tables of a DB is a bit more complicated for MsSQL, more complicated again for SQLite, and even more complicated for PgSQL :-(

Comment: If achieving cross-database compatibility is your real goal, you'll probably better using something like Doctrine (which implements lots of stuff related to DB-compatibility), might I add : PDO is nice, but it only abstract some differences (like not having to use mysqli_* or pg_* or ...) ;; it doesn't abstract the differences between SQL syntaxes that each DB engine understand.

Comment: That's why the docu at http://uk.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php says: "PDO does not provide a database abstraction"

Comment: "\dt" is not a PostgreSQL query, but just a command in psql commandline tool... However, there is a PG_TABLES table which may be interested for you. For SQLite there is SQLITE_MASTER table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a portable way to query for the schema, you can use the ansi standard [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)

Answer (score 2):

```
$alltables=$db->query("SHOW TABLES",PDO::FETCH_NUM);

while($result=$alltables->fetch()){

echo $result[0].'<br/>';
}
```

This is the exact code you want, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in a cross-platform way, look into [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com)'s [`Zend_Db`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html), which provides the [`listTables()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.list-describe) method